# Named entity recognition model always predicts the same class but gives accuracy of 99%

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, named-entity-recognition

I want to make Keras NER model that will tag profanity/swear words in the text.
I have dataset with more than 50k rows/sentences, but only 2000 rows out of the 50k contain the swear words.
I have trained my model with full dataset and only with rows that contain swear words and I got the same results. Loss is less than 0.1, accuracy is more than 99% but yet, when I want to predict, it tags all words the same (like those words are not swear words).

I have enumerated all words and labels in each row:

```
max_len = 50

X = [[word2idx.get(w[0], 0) for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=vocab_len-1)

y = [[label2idx[w[1]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=y, padding="post", value=label2idx["O"])
y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=num_labels) for i in y]
```

This is my model:

```
input_word = Input(shape=(max_len, ))

model = Embedding(input_dim = vocab_len+1, output_dim = 75, input_length = max_len)(input_word)
model = SpatialDropout1D(0.25)(model)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout = 0.2))(model)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_labels, activation = "softmax"))(model)

model = Model(input_word, out)
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 50)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 50, 75)            1506000   
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_2 (Spatial (None, 50, 75)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 50, 100)           50400     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 50, 3)             303       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,556,703
Trainable params: 1,556,703
Non-trainable params: 0

opt = Adam(lr = 0.000075)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='auto')
history = model.fit(x_train, 
                    y_train, 
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    epochs=100, 
                    batch_size=64,
                    callbacks = [es], 
                    verbose=2)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=64)
print("\nSCORE:", score)
```

Results of model training:

```
...
...
Epoch 55/100
4846/4846 - 8s - loss: 0.0193 - acc: 0.9940 - val_loss: 0.0307 - val_acc: 0.9933
1212/1212 [==============================] - 0s 254us/sample - loss: 0.0307 - acc: 0.9933
```

Prediction (sorry for bad words):

```
max_len = 50
list_of_sentances = ["Fucking fuck fuck you asshole bullshit fuck you bitch"]
word_num = list_of_sentances[0].split(" ")
word_num = len(word_num)

test = [[word2idx.get(w[0], 0) for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
test = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=test, padding="post", value=vocab_len-1)

pred = model.predict(test)
pred = pred.argmax(axis=-1)[0][:word_num]

labels = {v: k for k, v in label2idx.items()}

prediction = [labels[word] for word in pred]

print(labels)
print(prediction)

{0: 'O', 1: 'profanity'}
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong. I have tried the same principle for NER models when I wanted to find organization names, person names etc...and I got great results (this is the tutorial that I followed https://djajafer.medium.com/named-entity-recognition-and-classification-with-keras-4db04e22503d).

I can not use class_weights because I have sequences. Example of my 'classes' look like this:

```
No shit .           O profanity O
Ya bitch !          profanity profanity O
Shut the fuck up!   profanity profanity profanity profanity
```

Comment: Your dataset contains so few swear words that the model can get a great accuracy by simply predicting that nothing is a swear word. The problem you're faced with is called class imbalance - some ways of solving it is loss reweighting (changing your loss to punish false negatives more harshly) or resampling (to get a more balanced dataset).

Comment: How can I change my loss to punish false negatives more harshly?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Comment: This can not be done with class weights, I do not have general classes, I have sequences. Please check the end of the question, I have added the look of my data

Comment: You still have two classes, 0 and profanity. Did you try to implement it like it was done in the link and received an error, or did you just assume that it does not work? If the former is the case, I can get back to you and write an answer below with a custom loss function that can do this (in case you do not know how to create one yourself). If the latter is the case, please try to do it. The fact that you deal with sequences does not necessarily mean that you do not have binary output and thus class weights might still work.

Comment: I know how to add class weights. If I have two classes, lets say 0 and 1. And i have 5000 samples of 0 and 1000 samples of 1, i can write  {1:5, 0:1} for class weights, but I can not write {'profanity':5, "O":1}, because my classes are not profanity and O.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other members, the metric gives you 99% accuracy because it accounts both for swear and non-swear words: tagging all words as non-swear will already give you a very high rate, because the dataset is unbalanced.

You should probably use fscore metric (combination of precision / recall), largely used in ML/NLP, because it focuses on a specific class. In brief, it will not take into account the true negatives (i.e. correctly identified non-swear words) and will focus on true positives (swear words recognized as such), taking into account false positive (non-swear words recognized as swear words) and false negatives (swear not recognized) for precision and recall  respectively.